# Autohotkey combine mouse and keyboard?

Tags: autohotkey

Anyone knows why this wont work in autohotkey?:

```
~RButton & ~LButton & ~t::
```

It says its an invalid hotkey. But why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinations of three or more keys are not supported (https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Try this:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook
#UseHook

#if GetKeyState("RButton","P") && GetKeyState("LButton","P") 

    t:: 
    z:: 
    k:: 
    l::
    u::
        MsgBox, RButton + LButton + optional key
    return

#if
```

Comment: Great. this works great. One more question. Can I somehow make a key press optional. Something like (t|z|k|l|u):: ?

Comment: See my edited answer (If I understand you correctly).